# Query designer returns an unwanted entity field

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0, query-designer

I have a Reporting Services Project on SQL Server 2008 R2. The point is to provide users with a data model they can use as a data source for Report Builder 3. So I have created my data source views as usual and then the Report model with no problems.

For example in my model I have a table `Student` which has a relationship with table `Course` using a `CourseSK` key (one to one). So I am using `student.CourseSK = course.CourseSK` to return to the query designer only the `course.Coursename` field under the `Student` entity (I have hidden everything else from the `course` table.)

The problem is that when I test it in ReportBuilder, using the query designer when I add field `CourseName` from entity `student` in the dataset, it returns two fields instead of one: `CourseName` and `Course` where course returns some values like `AAAAAEAA =`. I guess is some object reference but can be very confusing to the end user. How can I make this disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it turns out to be a unique entity identifier used for aggregating fields with non unique values. It cannot be removed from the data set. More information here [Answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70b6e99d-63e0-4b8e-b770-f33d5e0f76bc/query-designer-alphabet-soup-column?forum=sqlreportingservices)